# Bootstrap putting a responsive image

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

Hi im now trying bootstrap for the first time and i cant seem to put an image in the bootstrap base 64 can anybody help me usually i use the

```
<img src=''>
```

This is my usual code in html5 and i know where to put the url or image path
where the image is located and the type of image it was

now im trying to put this code using bootstrap and I dont know how to use or make a responsive image

```
  <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" src="data:image/png;base64," class="img-thumbnail" alt="">
```

i also tried this website http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#thumbnails but i dont even know how to use it and i dont know where to put the image path can anybody help me im kind of a noob at bootstrap and thanks! any help would really be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys i had seen some answers and got this also thanks for trying!

```
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="image/untitled.png" alt="">
  </div>
```